# Is there any evidence for a bias towards perceiving darker surfaces as 'figure' rather than 'ground'?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception, vision

Given that surfaces which capture attention are more likely to be perceived as figures (or figures attract attention more than ground does?), is there a bias associated with the luminance of a surface? For example, we often see dark figures (*e.g.*, text) on white paper.

Do you know of any literature to suggest a bias where darker surfaces are shown to attract attention more effectively than lighter surfaces (or *vice versa*)?

Or, alternatively, is there data available on a possible bias where figure-ground segmentation is more likely to occur for a dark figure on a white ground (or *vice versa*)?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**
From my personal experience, I do not think darker surfaces are regarded preferably as the object, and light surfaces as the background.

**Background**
I have been pondering on this question for so long that I decided to post *an* answer. Perhaps it will draw attention from others who can give a more definitive answer.

This answer was inspired by [this question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/15868/is-the-rubin-vase-illusion-an-example-of-inattentional-blindness) on the **[Rubin Vase Illusion](http://psylux.psych.tu-dresden.de/i1/kaw/diverses%20Material/www.illusionworks.com/html/figure_ground.html)**. It is an **[ambiguous figure/ground illusion](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Figure-ground_perception)** which is thought to depend on the visual system analyzing scenes in terms of object (figure) and background (ground). You can see a vase when you regard the faces as background and *vice versa*. In the Fig. 1 below I have posted two versions of this illusion where the black and white portions are reversed. Personally, and hence anecdotally, I do not perceive a clear difference in the perception of the vase versus faces between both figures. Hence, based on this anecdotal evidence I tend to believe that the definition of figure and ground is independent on color (shades of gray in this case). I couldn't find references for the flip-flop rates or vase-versus-face perception time on the two stimuli, unfortunately. In all, what a great question!

[image] [image]
<sup>Fig. 1. Contrast-inverted Rubin Illusions. sources: [Winkler *et al*. (2006)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2855546/) (left panel) and [Russel & Dowey (2014)](http://www.intropsych.com/ch04_senses/gestalt_psychology.html) (right panel)</sup>

<sub>**References**

**-** [Russel & Dowey, *Psychology: An Introduction* (2014)](http://www.intropsych.com/ch04_senses/gestalt_psychology.html)

**-** [Winkler *et al*. *Eur J Neurosci* (2006); **24**(2): 625–34](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2855546/)</sub>